# why InfiniteScroll implementation updated only one time in React table?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-scroll, react-table

this is the fetchData function and it works the first time, the table updated 10 rows, but when you reach the end again nothing happens . what is the reason for this to work the first time only and not updating after ?

const [items , setItems] = useState(data);
const [hasMore , setHasMore] = useState(true)

```
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(10);


const fetchMoreData = () => {
  

    
    if (items.length >= items.length +1) {
        setHasMore( false );
      return;
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        setOffset( offset + 10);
     
    }, 100);
 
  };
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to provide a bit more code than this, but I suppose what you'll want to do is listen for changes in useEffect, and based on a condition, call your fetch function